# Server.ClearError() with page refresh

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-3.0

I am using ASP.NET custom error page in my application. Following is the web.config file entry for CustomErrors tag

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
```

Following is the code snippet on Error.aspx page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        { 
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if(ex != null)
            { 
                CommonUtils.SendException(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                Server.ClearError();
            }
        }
    }
```

If "ex" is not null, code will send the exception email. This works fine.

After sending email, I want to clear all the errors so that no email will be sent in case users hits the refresh button. But even after using Server.ClearError, there is a value return by  Server.GetLastError() When page is posted back.

Comment: why dont you keep this in Global.asax's `ApplicationError()` method and use server.transfer() to navigate to the error page

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be rewritten to something like this:
Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex= Server.GetLastError();
    CommonUtils.SendException(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString());
}
```

And the Page_Load event of error page should be empty then. As you can read in this MS article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306355 Server.ClearErrors stops error propagation, so If you call it on the page error will not be handled by Application_Error event. If you don't call it in Application_Error then application will look for customErrors declaration in web.config redirect to that page.

> If you do not call Server.ClearError or trap the error in the
>   Page_Error or Application_Error event handler, the error is handled
>   based on the settings in the  section of the Web.config
>   file. In the  section, you can specify a redirect page
>   as a default error page (defaultRedirect) or specify to a particular
>   page based on the HTTP error code that is raised. You can use this
>   method to customize the error message that the user receives.
>
> If an error occurs that is not trapped at any of the previous levels
>   in your application, this custom page is displayed. This section
>   demonstrates how to modify the Global.asax file so that
>   Server.ClearError is never called. As a result, the error is handled
>   in the Web.config file as the last point to trap the error.

Comment: The link is dead, so for future people, try: https://web.archive.org/web/20150315090236/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306355